# Prevent JS firing more than once unless window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a transition on some image elements on our site and they work fine apart from when you scroll up the site they fire again. These should only fire when you scroll down the site or the window resizes.

Current JS:

```
var $animation_elements = jQuery('.animation-element');
var $window = jQuery(window);

function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

  jQuery.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = jQuery(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
        (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
      $element.addClass('in-view');
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('in-view');
    }
  });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');
```

Is there a way to prevent this firing twice or only once unless window resize?

Comment: something like that would the trick on resized at least
```var resized = false
$(window).resize(function(){
   resized = true; 
   // do stuff
  resized false
 });```

you have a var where you can track resizing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to let only the resize event triggered?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $animation_elements = jQuery('.animation-element');
var $window = jQuery(window);
//Initialize classes
jQuery.each($animation_elements, function(index, element) {
  jQuery(element).addClass('in-view');
});
function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

  jQuery.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = jQuery(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
        (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
      $element.addClass('in-view');
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('in-view');
    }
  });
}

$window.on('resize', check_if_in_view);
check_if_in_view();
});
```

Comment: Doing this meant that it didn't fire at all unless resized. Still did it to fire atleast once when scrolling down the site

Comment: That only works for the first element on the page. there are however multiple

Comment: Example url: goo.gl/NzYC6G

Comment: Again, trigger it after the elements are loaded, modifying answer again.

Comment: @BenH please don't use URL shorteners.

Comment: Maybe you need to initialize the classes first, editing one last time...

Comment: So it does it to the ones that are in view on load but then nothing after that. I appreciate your help. Thanks